# How to restrict django by taken letter 'e' in integer field in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is my code for integer field in `models.py`

```
qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='empty')
```

Any Ideas!!

Comment: What does this have to do with "taken letter 'e'"?

Answer (score 0):

`PositiveIntegerField` needs to be a positive integer and 'empty' isn't.  Try

```
qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```